# Javamail how to send encrypted mime

Tags: android, encryption, jakarta-mail, mime-message

Is there any ideas how to send encrypted mime to recipients addresses by SMTPTransport.

```
SMTPTransport transport = (SMTPTransport) session.getTransport("smtp");
transport.connect(host, port,username, password);    
transport.sendMessage(encryptedMimeMessage,  nonEncryptedMsg.getAllRecipients());
transport.close();
```

I couldn't change encrypted mime but i have to send mimeMessage, please give me a solution how can i set From and Recipients address except changing EncryptedMimeMessage